# How to upload a JavaScript file variable to a server?

Tags: javascript, php, uploading

I have a variable in Javascript which is an encrypted uploaded file. What is my best option to upload that variable to a web server? I tried [simpleUpload.js](http://simpleupload.michaelcbrook.com) and I can't seem to get `encryptedFile.simpleUpload("upload.php")` to work. The file is valid, as I can download it and decrypt it fine. Thank you.

Comment: so, you have a php "server"

Comment: You should use an AJAX request with your `upload.php` file. Read [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @Maramal simpleUpload handles the AJAX I believe. When running the simpleUpload function, I get `'fileenc.simpleUpload("/upload.php", {})', 'fileenc.simpleUpload' is undefined)`

Comment: So... did you try to run `console.log(encryptedFile)` to debug your code?

Comment: The file itself is fine, like I said, I'm able to download it and decrypt it without problems. Is there another library that may help with uploading file variables? All that I can find are libraries that upload file inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option for is to use ajax to upload it to the server

```html
$ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url : "upload.php",
  data: "put the encrypted file here",
  success: function(response){
  // what you want to happen after success is returned
  },
  error : function(error){
    // handle any error response here 
    }
});
```

Comment: If you choose to supply a code snippet, you should specify what libraries the snippet depends on.

Comment: @noahnu oh sorry i forget that , it jquery , check here for the docs http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Worked, but I had to add `processData: false,` for any future readers.